# Telerik Report Designer renders blank report

Tags: mysql, telerik, telerik-reporting

It's not a blank page but the entire report is blank.

When I create a connection I go to the Data tab and add an SQL Datasource. I configure a Datasource and Build a new Data connection and choose a MySQL Data Provider and build the connection string to my database. Then choose embedded in report definition. And for the Source command I choose a stored procedure with a parameter. I leave the source parameter value blank while configuring the datasource
. 
Then here is the weird part... when I preview the data source results by clicking the Execute Query and type in an appropriate parameter the data displays just fine just like the stored procedure in MySQL Workbench. But if I try to preview the report and type in my parameter in the parameters collector the entire report is blank. What's even weirder is if I type in the static value in the Parameters -> ParameterName -> Value the report renders fine. This has completely stumped me. I've done `IS NOT NULL` check on all of the fields in the table I'm querying but there's no change.

The parameter that's configured in the report is a string and the parameter in the stored procedure is a string as well. If I do a `where column like Concat('%',param,'%')` then it will bring back every result in the database. Almost as if it's modifying the typed in parameter that's being sent to the stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out....and it's a stupid mistake.

When you're on the Configure Data Source Parameters screen when configuring a datasource you have to set the parameter Value = Parameters.Param.Value